# Get a process executable name from process ID

Tags: windows, winapi

I am currently trying to get the names of a list of programs whose pid I have.

The program is run as administrator, but `GetModuleFileNameEx` fails with error code 5.

I open the program with `OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE,PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION)` and I have the `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` enabled.

Comment: How are you opening the process? Can you show the surrounding code?

Comment: Oh, and why not use [GetProcessImageFileName](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=GetProcessImageFileName)?

Comment: GetProcessImageFileName returns "\" for each process, but no errorcode whatsoever. : /

Comment: The reason you're getting "\" returned is because you're using the wrong character encoding - the API is returning 2 bytes, you're using 1 byte. The "\" represents the device form of path:  
\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1\Windows\System32\Ctype.nls  
As mentioned in the documentation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217(v=vs.85).aspx  
You need to sort the character encoding problems out first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The process handle passed to [GetModuleFileNameEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) requires `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` and `PROCESS_VM_READ` access rights.

This worked for me:

```
HANDLE h = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ,
                       FALSE,
                       6088);
if (0 == h)
{
    std::cerr << "OpenProcess() failed: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
}
else
{
    char exe_path[2048] = {};

    if (GetModuleFileNameEx(h, 0, exe_path, sizeof(exe_path) - 1))
    {
        std::cout << exe_path << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "GetModuleFileNameEx() failed: " <<
            GetLastError() << "\n";
    }
    CloseHandle(h);
}
```

However, as others have pointed out (and is also stated in documentation for GetModuleFileNameEx()) there are safer ways to acquire this information:

- [GetProcessImageFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [QueryFullProcessImageName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: GetModuleFilename now returns Errorcode 299 for some processes and "C" for others, but not the full process name

Comment: @jgpt, errorcode 299 will be returned if the binary calling `GetModuleFileNameEx()` is 32-bit and the target process is 64-bit. Is this what your are doing? Not sure what you mean by "C": that is the name of exe? If so, sounds like the size of the buffer being passed is 2 bytes as "C" is commonly the drive name.

Comment: +1 but note that the same is true of GetProcessImageFileName(). Although OpenProcess() had succeeded for SYNCHRONIZE access, I was getting error 5 passing that handle to GetProcessImageFileName(). Changing the OpenProcess() call to request PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ caused GetProcessImageFileName() to succeed with the resulting handle.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/Win32-Kernel/31390865/getmodulefilename-refuses-to-return-a-filename.aspx) that error is returned when there's not enough information to return the filename.