# Determine a process's exe path including elevated processes

Tags: c, winapi

I want to get the exe path of a process. I can do this fine but for elevated processes I am unable to call `OpenProcess()` (error is 'Access Denied').

Is it possible to determine the exe path of any process without needing elevated privileges? Maybe I don't need to open/access to the process to determine this?

The following `OpenProcess` fails for elevated processes:

```
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processId); 

... 
QueryFullProcessImageName(hProcess, 0, exePath, &len)
```

Comment: Try removing `PROCESS_VM_READ` access specificator. Also you could use `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` instead of `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION `

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475009/get-a-process-executable-name-from-process-id

Comment: Did you read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `PROCESS_VM_READ` access specificator, since it is not needed for the [`QueryFullProcessImageName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919(v=vs.85).aspx) function. The documentation describes the required process handle access rights as follows:

> A handle to the process. This handle must be created with the PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION access right.